# Django ссылочная навигация на сайте

Tags: django

Меня интересует тема касаемая ссылочной навигации в `Django`. 
Это очень удобно и правильно со стороны юзабилити. Пример ниже.
[image: Пример]
Мне нужно сделать тоже самое и я искал готовые примеры, но ничего толкового не нашел. Может быть кто-нибудь встречался с этим? Если да, подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать, какую лучше таблетку использовать или приведите небольшой пример. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А при чём тут Django? Пишите в html-коде что вашей душе угодно.

Comment: И это, кстати, называется хлебные крошки (breadcrumbs)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за информацию, буду знать теперь хоть как гуглить. А по поводу html я не уверен. Мне кажется там логика определенная.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, например можно сделать как-нибудь так

```py
class Category(models.Model):

    #название категории
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 

    #slug
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    #родительская категория
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    #уровень вложенности категории
    level = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    #метод получения url категории (стандартный для джанго)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_view', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    #метод, который будет получать все названия и ссылки родителей
    def get_all_parents(self):
        if self.level > 0:
            all_parents = []
            obj = self.parent
            for i in range(0, self.level):
                name = obj.name
                link = obj.get_absolute_url()
                all_parents.append([name, link])
                if i < self.level:
                    obj = obj.parent
            return all_parents
        else:
            return None
```

Уровень вложенности можно получать, переопределив метод save у модели. Но надо не забыть, что при изменении родителя уровни вложенности нужно переопредлять не только у текущей категории, но и у ее дочерних.

Ну а вообще, погуглите про деревья в джанго. Вроде бы они решают вашу проблему.